# Confused about deriving the SNR at the input for an amplifier circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, snr

[image]

I'm learning about noise sources in circuits (and minimising them) but I'm having trouble understanding how I would derive the input SNR for an amplifier circuit with a voltage divided input. Without the voltage divider I would have just used the input voltage divided by its source resistance \$R_s\$, but with the voltage divider I can't make sense of treating the noise from the two resistances as if they were a source resistance while only considering the voltage after the divider as the input signal. However I can't seem to think of a more sensible way to measure the input SNR.

This is my circuit:

[image]

Assume that \$R_2\$ gives a variable resistance of up to \$\pm20\Omega\$ corresponding to amplifier input of \$\pm 50\text{ mV}\$.

Given the voltage divider in this situation, is the input signal 50 mV or the +5 V rail? And is the noise input just \$N_{R1}+N_{R2}\$?

For calculating the amplifier's input SNR I'm using the formula:

$$ \text{SNR} = \frac{\text{Signal}_\text{in}}{\text{Noise}_\text{in}} $$

I would have assumed that it would be the signal into the op amp (50 mV) divided by the noise sources \$N_{R1}\$ and \$N_{R2}\$, however with these values my overall SNR seems way too low.

Comment: Please draw the full circuit showing the input and full op-amp connections.

Comment: Are you familiar with Thevenin equivalent circuits? This concept will help you determine the source impedance correctly.

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg, updated question to include full circuit schematic

Comment: @Andyaka, I've included the full amplifier however didn't think it was necessary since I'm only asking about the SNR into the circuit